# XSLT filter XML except certen elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I wanting to filter an XML.
The ones i get are pretty big with lots of useless information for me.

I just need a few elements with text from this files. 
This is almost what it lookes like.

```
<root>
  <customerinfo1>...</customerinfo1>
  <customerinfo2>...</customerinfo2>
  <productinfo>
    <productinfo1>...</productinfo1>
    <productinfo2...></productinfo2>
      <textarea>
        <other1>...</other1>
        <other2>...</other2>
        <text1>abc</text1>
        <text2>cab</text2>
        <text3>bca</text3>
        <other3>...</other3>
      </textarea>
  </productinfo>
</root>
```

This is almost what it lookes like. Not all  elements have text. I want to take the  elements with text in them and add them to one element.
What i want is something similar to this.

```
<placement>
<text>Text from text1 text2 or text3</text>
</placement>
```

What XSLT i did and what it did. 
So i manage to sort it to just the text elements, but not group them to one element. 
And the big problem is that all text disappears from `<text>No text here</text>` and i get elemets that where empty from the begining in XML.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(),'text')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <placement>
          <text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </text>
        </placement>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you precisely show what the output should look like when processing the boiled down example source you gave at the top of your question?

Comment: Do you want to map the `root` element to a new `placement` element? Or do you want to map each `textarea` element to a new `placement` element? And your wanted output sample should show the data from the input sample you want to output, otherwise it is difficult to tell what you want. As for your code, if you remove the first template and replace the second `match="node()|@*"` with `match="root"` and the `xsl:apply-templates/>` in it with `<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[starts-with(name(),'text')]/>`, you might get what you want.

Comment: Okej, let me clarify. I want the `textarea` to become `placement` and the `text1, text2, text3` to become one `<text>Text from text1, 2 and 3 here </text>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the textarea to become placement and the text1, text2, text3 to
>   become one `<text>Text from text1, 2 and 3 here </text>`

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <placement>
        <text>
            <xsl:value-of select="//textarea/*[starts-with(name(),'text')]"/>
        </text>
    </placement>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example (after correcting `<productinfo2..>`), the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<placement>
   <text>abc cab bca</text>
</placement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. This worked great with a little edit.
Hade to change the select tag to

`<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[starts-with(name(),'text')]"/>`

Text elements was not in order more like this

```
<other1>...</other1>
<text1>abc</text1>
<other2>...</other2>
<text2>cab</text2>
<text3>bca</text3>
<other3>...</other3>
```

Comment: `select="//*[starts-with(name(),'text')]"` is not a good idea, because it will select `textarea` too. I don't see what the order has to do with it: the `other..` elements will be skipped either way.

Comment: I dont really know why but then i select //textarea/* it only selects the value of the first text1 abc not text2 and text3 values. When i write is as i told i get the values of all three but no spaces between dem. output "abccabbca" what i want is what you wrote "abc cab bca"

Comment: Are you sure your processor supports XSLT 2.0 ?

Comment: Im starting to think its not supported because its not using functions. Ill have to look into some solution for 1.0 and see if it works.